# How do I pass a dbFailOnError parameter using C# interop?

Tags: c#, ms-access, office-interop

I'm using DAO to execute SQL statements on an Access database.  If I was using VBA, I could use `dbFailOnError` to throw an error if an update query fails, like so:

```
function updateTable(db as DAO.Database) as boolean

 on error goto errHandler
 db.execute "update testTable set name='xyz' where name='abc'",dbFailOnError
 updateTable=true
 exit function

 errhandler:
  updateTable=false
  on error goto 0

end function
```

How do I pass `dbFailOnError` using .NET Interop?  It seems that the equivalent would be:

```
using Dao = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao;
namespace DatabaseFunctions
{
    public class Updater
    {
        public bool updateTable(Dao.Database db)
        {
            try
            {
             db.Execute("update testTable set name='xyz' where name='abc'",
                         dbFailOnError);
             return true;
            }
            catch
            {
             return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But what namespace do I find `dbFailOnError` in?  It's not in `Dao`.

Comment: great, thanks.  I'll accept if you post this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbFailOnError` is a member of the `DAO` enum, `RecordsetOptionEnum` ... so try `DAO.RecordsetOptionEnum.dbFailOnError`